# Puppet 5 : Variables not interpolated

Tags: puppet, hiera

I'm trying to update an old Puppet 3 infrastructure to Puppet 5.

I'm using Hiera to get the data, with a NoSQL backend. I've written my own ENC in order to get node data from there, and this is working well.

However, when I put variables in Hiera, they don't get interpolated. For example, let's say that I want an Apache vhost to listen on the fqdn of the host :

```
 "apache::vhost": {
   "my-vhost": {
     "servername": "%{fqdn}"
   }
 }
```

(I've reduced it in order to get to the point)

When I run puppet on my node, the variable is not replaced and I find `ServerName %{fqdn}` in my Apache configuration.

Does someone already had this problem ? I have no idea left on what to do now...

Thank you very much !

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use one of `"%{::fqdn}"`, `"%{facts.fqdn}"`, or `"%{facts.networking.fqdn}"`.

Which NoSQL backend are you using? I would validate using one of either the YAML or JSON backends to rule out the NoSQL backend.